# Strange error after deploy: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have been struggling with the error for many days but couldn't find an answer!
I use Spring MVC + Hibernate + mySQL + Appache Tomcat.

My dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers"/>

    <bean id="annotationHandlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    </bean>

    <bean id="methodHandlerAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fileCreator" class="com.utilites.FileCreator">

    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Overhaul</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">3</property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        </property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="com.springmvc.Question"/>
        <mapping resource="Question.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

WelcomeController.java:

```
package com.controllers;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

And jdbc.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Overhaul
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

After deploy I can seen the next stacktrace in web-browser:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'welcomeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.controllers.WelcomeController.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:326)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Please, help me!!!

Comment: For starters you might want to use the correct transaction manager. You are using the `hibernate3` one whereas you want to use the `hibernate4` one. Or maybe the other way around. Also your `hibernate.cfg.xml` is flawed, your `connection.*` properties are useless as you are injection a datasource and setting the `current_session_context_class` to `thread` breaks proper tx management. You want to remove all properties only leave the mappings in there. However the likely cause of the error is a missing jar, `hibernate-annotations` in a matching version for hibernate 4.

Comment: @M. Deinum, I absolutely agree with statement, that I mixed with versions of Hibernate. I changed from 4 to 3 in dispatcher-servlet.xml. I have `hibbernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final` in pom.xml. After these manipulations, I've got next error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: `Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;`

Comment: Which hibernate version do you use? Could you please add that to your post. The new error imho indicates that you are missing the hibernate-core jar in the correct version. I seriously hope that you are using a dependency manager (maven, gradle) to manage your dependencies and that you are not searching the internet yourself?

Comment: @M. Deinum, I try to use Hib4 and Spring4. I use maven and there are `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` dependencies of 4.1.9.Final version. Could you give me proper pom.xml to create working example?

Comment: If you have using hibernate4 then also use the classes from the hibernate4 package don't try to use the hibernate3 ones with Hibernate 4. You need to use the [`hibernate-commons-annotations`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.hibernate.common%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-commons-annotations%22) package

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not at all related to your code. Its actually with the dependencies. You must have already found a solution. But I am posting the answer just in case anyone else comes up with similar issue.

I had a similar issue and what I did is, I actually upgraded my hibernate version to 5.1.0 and then added hibernate-commons-annotations 5.0.1.Final. So my dependencies are now like below.

[image]

The specific, Hibernate core will have hibernate-common-annotation and this has the missing class

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
```